# How to change reference highlight color in ssms 2017?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

In ssms2017 text editor, when you click some words(variable/field/tablename..etc), others same words would highlight, but this color not enough HIGHLIGHT, I want change it, but i can't find out the item in Tool>options>font and color.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors.

Under Display items select "Brace Matching (Rectangle)" and change the item background.

https://documentation.red-gate.com/sp7/files/38667551/38863411/1/1410951304827/prompt+change+highlight+color.png

[image]

**Example Result**

[image]

Comment: this actually changed the background color from the white background for me. not the background color when we highlight like you've shown..

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was using the Highlighted Reference option.  This helps when you're using tools like SQL Complete that like to highlight a lot.

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors.
Under Display items select "Highlighted Reference" and change the item foreground and background options.

[image: SSMS Highlighted Reference Option]

[image: Code Example with the Highlighted Reference changes]